# How to update redis cache in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii, redis-cache

I am trying to re-set the cache but every time I did that, the expiration time kept alive. How can I UPDATE the redis cache without effect the expiration time.

```
$cache = Yii::app()->cache;
if($cache->get($md5)){
    $md5Values = $cache->get($md5);
    $md5Values['repetition'] +=1;
    $md5Values['priority'] = 2;var_dump($cache->get($md5));
    $cache->set($md5,$md5Values);
    if ($md5Values['repetition'] > 10 && $md5Values['repetition'] <= 1000){

        $md5Values['priority'] = 1;
        $cache->set($md5,$md5Values);
        var_dump($cache->get($md5));
        return  array('priority'=>1);
    } elseif ($md5Values['repetition'] > 1000){
        $md5Values['priority'] = 0;
        $cache->set($md5,$md5Values);
        return  array('priority'=>0);
    }
    return false;
}else{
    $cacheArray=array();
    $cacheArray['repetition'] = 1;
    $cacheArray['priority'] = 2;
    $cache->set($md5,$cacheArray,30);
    return false;
}
```